# Removing existing line to replace with new value in httpd.conf

Tags: shell, vim, sed

```
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module /usr/jboss/jbossweb/navapp_ws1/modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/jboss/jbossweb/navapp_ws1/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module /usr/jboss/jbossweb/navapp_ws1/modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module /usr/jboss/jbossweb/navapp_ws1/modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module /usr/jboss/jbossweb/navapp_ws1/modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module /usr/jboss/jbossweb/navapp_ws1/modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module /usr/jboss/jbossweb/navapp_ws1/modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dtsagent /www/apps/dynatrace/dynatrace.so
```

I want to find 
`LoadModule dtsagent /www/apps/dynatrace/dynatrace.so`
in this file and remove all that have `LoadModule dtsagent ........`

Currently I'm working with this to add the line below the same block
`grep -q -F 'LoadModule dtagent_module' $jvm_home/$webservers/conf/httpd.conf || 
            sed "/^LoadModule/,/^$/!b;/^$/i\LoadModule dtagent_module /www/apps/dynatrace/$webservers/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so" -i file`

Comment: Unclear what exactly you want to achieve. Just a guess, is `grep -v "^LoadModule dtsagent"` perhaps helpful?

Comment: You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the unclear questions. So basically i just want to find all lines that match "LoadModule dtsagent" and remove.

Comment: That sounds like a requirement fulfilled by @DevSolar `grep -v ..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is easy for sed:

```
sed '/^LoadModule dtsagent/d' httpd.conf
```

sed will look for any line starting `/^LoadModule dtsagent/` and delete that line. The "^" indicates the start of the line. Remove it if your search term can be anywhere in the line.

Comment: Thxs John, this is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the global ex command**

If you are editing the httpd.conf file in Vim, you could issue the global ex command:

`:g/^LoadModule dtsagent/d`

In words, this just means to find all lines matching the pattern and delete:

`^LoadModule dtsagent`

I chose to use the anchor, `^` to indicate that we want to find this pattern beginning at the start of the line.

Lastly, once a match is found, I want the line deleted so I place the delete line command at the end, `d`.